# SVG error for path "d" attribute

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to dynamically create a path using JavaScript, but the `d` attribute keeps giving an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.`

```
var location = document.createElementNS(svgns,"path");
    location.setAttributeNS("fill-rule","evenodd");
    location.setAttributeNS("fill","#ffffff");
    location.setAttributeNS("clip-rule","evenodd");
    location.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M57.295,27.757c-11.896,0-21.539,9.643-21.539,21.539S57.295,86.5,57.295,86.5
    s21.539-25.309,21.539-37.205S69.19,27.757,57.295,27.757z M57.295,60.039c-6.373,0-11.539-5.166-11.539-11.539
    s5.166-11.539,11.539-11.539S68.833,42.127,68.833,48.5S63.667,60.039,57.295,60.039z");

    locationBTn.appendChild(locationStroke0);
    locationBTn.appendChild(location);

    document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(locationBTn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when specifying path data as you have here. The line breaks can cause trouble.

As a simplified example:

```
location.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M5.5,
27.2,
c11.89,
0-21.5,9.6");
```

is not the same as

```
location.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M5.5,27.2,c11.89,0-21.5,9.6");
```

---

You have a couple options:

**A) Put it all on one line:**

```
location.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M57.295,27.757c-11.896,0-21.539,9.64321.539,21.539S57.295,86.5,57.295,86.5s21.539-25.309,21.539-37.205S69.19,27.757,57.295,27.757z M57.295,60.039c-6.373,0-11.539-5.166-11.539-11.539s5.166-11.539,11.539-11.539S68.833,42.127,68.833,48.5S63.667,60.039,57.295,60.039z");
```

*(which can be hard to read and work with)*

**B) Use several strings and the + operator:**

```
location.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M57.295,27.757"+
"c-11.896,0-21.539,9.64321.539,21.539S57.295,86.5,57.295,86.5s21.539-25.309,21.539-37.205S69.19,27.757,57.295,27.757z "+
"M57.295,60.039"+
"c-6.373,0-11.539-5.166-11.539-11.539s5.166-11.539,11.539-11.539S68.833,42.127,68.833,48.5S63.667,60.039,57.295,60.039z");
```

*(perhaps the most common solution)*

or

**C) Use \ to escape the return character and get a multi-line string:**

```
location.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M57.295,27.757c-11.896,0\
-21.539,9.64321.539,21.539S57.295,86.5,57.295,86.5s21.539-25.309,\
21.539-37.205S69.19,27.757,57.295,27.757z M57.295,60.039c-6.373,\
0-11.539-5.166-11.539-11.539s5.166-11.539,11.539\
-11.539S68.833,42.127,68.833,48.5S63.667,60.039,57.295,60.039z");
```

*(an odd but valid solution)*

---

For more information on exactly which characters may be used in the "d" string for SVG, check out http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF

---

*PS - Make sure `locationStroke0);` isn't a typo for `locationStroke);`!*